# Linq Getting Index of Datatable and updating Collection

Tags: c#, linq

i have a Class collection contained in a list that tells me what changes have been made to an excel sheet. For example if a cell has changed in an excel sheet the class contains a property such as the rowid, row index and the cell address. In addition I also have a datatable which mirrors what is on the excel sheet just with an identification column. What I am trying to do is update the Class collection thru a linq statement that finds index of the datatable where the ids match and set it into the collection So far I have this linq statement which returns 0 for the row index

```
  ExcelCollectionDetail.Join(Datatable.AsEnumerable(),
                ExcelCellChange => ExcelCellChange.Id,
                dt => dt.Field<string>(id),
                (ExcelCellChange , dt) => new { CellChange, dt})
            .Select((Obj, index) => new { Obj, index })
            .Where(x => x.dt.Field<string>(id) == x.Obj.ExcelCellChange.Id).ToList()
            .ForEach(x => {
              int RowIndex = x.index;
              x.Obj.CellChange.CellRowIndex = RowIndex;
            });
```

Comment: You are doing a lot of different things in that one statement. Separate it out into different parts and find where the error is occurring. Once you do that, you can create a more specific question

Comment: I am trying to find the index of a Datatable row based off of a matching id in a collection and datatable row id

Comment: ForEach returns `void`. Only show code that is part of your problem.